# Spring data Neo4j Affected row count

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Considering a Spring Boot, neo4j environment with Spring-Data-neo4j-4 I want to make a delete and get an error message when it fails to delete.

My problem is since the Repository.delete() returns void I have no ideia if the delete modified anything or not.

First question: is there any way to get the last query affected lines? for example in plsql I could do SQL%ROWCOUNT

So anyway, I tried the following code:

```
public void deletesomething(Long somethingId) {
    somethingRepository.delete(getExistingsomething(somethingId).getId());
}

private something getExistingsomething(Long somethingId, int depth) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(somethingRepository.findOne(somethingId, depth))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new somethingNotFoundException(somethingId));
}
```

In the code above I query the database to check if the value exist before I delete it.
Second question: do you recommend any different approach?

So now, just to add some complexity, I have a cluster database and db1 can only Create, Update and Delete, and db2 and db3 can only Read (this is ensured by the cluster sockets). db2 and db3 will receive the data from db1 from the replication process.
For what I seen so far replication can take up to 90s and that means that up to 90s the database will have a different state.

Looking again to the code above:

```
public void deletesomething(Long somethingId) {
    somethingRepository.delete(getExistingsomething(somethingId).getId());
}
```

in debug that means:

```
getExistingsomething(somethingId).getId() // will hit db2
somethingRepository.delete(...) // will hit db1
```

and so if replication has not inserted the value in db2 this code wil throw the exception.
the second question is: without changing those sockets is there any way for me to delete and give the correct response?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported in Spring Data Neo4j, if you wish please open a feature request.

In the meantime, perhaps the easiest work around is to fall down to the OGM level of abstraction.

- Create a class that is injected with `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session`
- Use the following method on `Session`

**Example:** *(example is in Kotlin, which was on hand)*

```
fun deleteProfilesByColor(color : String)
{
    var query = """
    MATCH (n:Profile {color: {color}})
    DETACH DELETE n;
    """

    val params = mutableMapOf(
            "color" to color
    )

    val result = session.query(query, params)
    val statistics = result.queryStatistics() //Use these!
}
```